# Embed Album Cover to mp3 with Mutagen in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, mp3, mutagen

[ID3](http://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/id3.html?highlight=apic).
This is the Python 3 API, i'm not sure how to embed an image, so far I have this where I change the tags,

```
def addMetaData(url, title, artist, album, track):

    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open('img.jpg', 'wb') as out_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
    del response

    audio = MP3(filename=title+".mp3", ID3 = EasyID3)
    audio['artist'] = artist
    audio['title'] = title
    audio['tracknumber'] = track
    audio['album'] = album

    audio.save()
```

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](/help/mcve), with a **clear problem statement**.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think it is possible to embed albumart using `EasyID3` but it is possible with `ID3`.

You can embed albumart using `ID3` like below:

```
from mutagen.id3 import ID3, APIC

audio = ID3('music_file.mp3')

with open('img.jpg', 'rb') as albumart:
    audio['APIC'] = APIC(
                      encoding=3,
                      mime='image/jpeg',
                      type=3, desc=u'Cover',
                      data=albumart.read()
                    )

audio.save()
```

If performance is not your major concern, you can save textual metadata with `EasyID3` and then load the music file again using `ID3` to embed albumart. Otherwise, you can work completely using `ID3`.

So, your code in 1st case will be:

```
import requests
import shutil

# you can directly import EasyID3 and ID3
from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3
from mutagen.id3 import ID3, APIC

def addMetaData(url, title, artist, album, track):

    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open('img.jpg', 'wb') as out_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
    del response

    audio = EasyID3('music_file.mp3')
    audio['artist'] = artist
    audio['title'] = title
    audio['tracknumber'] = track
    audio['album'] = album
    audio.save()

    audio = ID3('music_file.mp3')
    with open('img.jpg', 'rb') as albumart:
        audio['APIC'] = APIC(
                          encoding=3,
                          mime='image/jpeg',
                          type=3, desc=u'Cover',
                          data=albumart.read()
                        )            
    audio.save()
```

In 2nd case:

```
import requests
import shutil

from mutagen.id3 import ID3, TPE1, TIT2, TRCK, TALB, APIC

def addMetaData(url, title, artist, album, track):

    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open('img.jpg', 'wb') as out_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
    del response

    audio = ID3('music_file.mp3')
    audio['TPE1'] = TPE1(encoding=3, text=artist)
    audio['TIT2'] = TALB(encoding=3, text=title)
    audio['TRCK'] = TRCK(encoding=3, text=track)
    audio['TALB'] = TALB(encoding=3, text=album)

    with open('img.jpg', 'rb') as albumart:
        audio['APIC'] = APIC(
                          encoding=3,
                          mime='image/jpeg',
                          type=3, desc=u'Cover',
                          data=albumart.read()
                        )            
    audio.save()
```

Note: You can also directly embed the albumart using `urllib2` without having to save it on disk first. Example:

```
import urllib2
from mutagen.id3 import ID3, APIC

audio = ID3('music_file.mp3')
albumart = urllib2.urlopen(url)

audio['APIC'] = APIC(
                  encoding=3,
                  mime='image/jpeg',
                  type=3,
                  desc=u'Cover',
                  data=albumart.read()
                )

albumart.close()
audio.save()
```

Comment: **Note**: `encoding=3` means `encoding=Encoding.UTF8` and `type=3` means `type=PictureType.COVER_FRONT` .
Not forget `from mutagen.id3 import Encoding, PictureType`

Comment: For the 2nd case: it should be audio['TIT2'] = TIT2(encoding=3, text=title)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the shutil call to instead write to the file you opened:

```
...
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with open('img.jpg', 'wb') as out_file:
    out_file.write(response.raw)
...
```